# escape for "{" inside C# 6 string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I am hoping to use a "{" inside a string interpolation statement but I'm having trouble finding the escape character to do it.

```
var val = "ERROR_STATE";
var str = $"if(inErrorState){ send 1,\"{val}\" }"
```

Desired output:

```
if(inErrorState){send 1,"ERROR_STATE"}
```

The simple solution is to just not use string interpolation, but I think this way of doing it is easier to read.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Type `{` twice to escape it:

```
$"if(inErrorState){{send 1, \"{val}\" }}"
```

BTW you can do the same with double quotes.